# C - Error returning structure pointer across multiple files

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am trying to learn how to separate C code into multiple files, but I am running into an error when doing so.

Relevant code (separated by file):

ex6.h:

```
#ifndef __ex6_h__
#define __ex6_h__

struct nlist { /* table entry: */
    struct nlist *next; /* next entry in chain */
    char *name; /* defined name */
    char *defn; /* replacement text */
};

#endif
```

list.c:

```
#include "ex6.h"

struct nlist *install(char *name, char *defn)
{
    struct nlist *np;
    unsigned hashval;

    if ((np = lookup(name)) == NULL) { /* not found */
        np = (struct nlist *) malloc(sizeof(*np));
        if (np == NULL || (np->name = strdup(name) == NULL)
            return NULL;
        hashval = hash(name);
        np->next = hashtab[hashval];
        hashtab[hashval] = np;
    } else /* already there */
        free((void *) np->defn); /*free previous defn */
    if ((np->defn = strdup(defn)) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    return np;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include "ex6.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct nlist *np1;

    np1 = install("This", "That");

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this code, I get this:

```
cc -g main.c list.c -o main
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:10:6: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  np1 = install("This", "That");
  ^
```

There is obviously more code than this (will post if requested), but every other part of the code seems to work fine except this snippets. Also, when I put the code from my "main.c" file and "list.c" into the same file the the code works fine.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a declaration of the install function in the header file. This makes the compiler assume it returns `int` rather than a pointer, which causes this warning. Add to ex6.h:

```
struct nlist *install(char *name, char *defn);
```

Comment: That would definitely help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation unit with main does not see the declaration of function `install`. So the compiler supposes that the function by default has return type `int` and that in this statement

`np1 = install("This", "That");`.

a value of type `int` is assigned to pointer to the structure.

You should include the function declaration in header "ex6.h" because the function is used in more than one compilation unit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a declaration for `install` in `ex6.h`. Something like:

```
extern struct nlist *install(char *name, char *defn);
```

Without a declaration, the assumed return values of functions are `int`. The compiler complains because the type of `np1` is `struct nlist*` and it tries to assign an `int` to `np1`.

When you provide the declaration, it knows the return type of `install` is `struct nlist*`. Hence, it is OK to assign the return value of `install` to `np1`.